# Navigation Bar Behavior iOS

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I'm in trouble with the `navigationBar` of `iOS`.
I have a `UIViewController`, let's call it `FirstViewController`,
which modifies the `navigationbar` **Alpha**.

I have some items which contains some Cities picture, and when click on item, I push a new Controller which is exactly the same controller (let's call it `SecondViewController`), so in logical way, **"the nav bar should be the same on `FirstViewController` AND on `SecondViewController`, but it's not the case"**.

I used breakpoints to know if the function that changes the nav bar alpha was called (it was `ViewWillAppear`.), and it was called twice (once for `FirstViewController`, and once for `SecondViewController`).

I have no idea why the behavior is like this, so if anyone has any idea it's cool !

Comment: try to set same alpha in secondViewController viewWillAppear method

Comment: The secondViewController is a firstViewController, so all methods are exactly the same

Comment: show code of viewWillAppear that may help to understand problem

Comment: let textAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.0)]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()